# A lot of non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a few functions that are very performance critical. They are quite generic and they depend on about 12 parameters apart from 2 inputs.

These parameters are fixed and I have 4 or 5 set of values (a1..a10) (b1..b10), etc... I could write the function a few times but for efficiency and maintainability I want to use non-type templates.

Imagine something like:

```
template <int a, int b, int c, int d, ..., int m>
double f(double x, double y) 
{ 
    return a*x+a*b*y+c+d+..+a*x*y; // some very complex math code
}
```

and it is only used in these N ways:

```
f<1,2,3,...,6>(x,y)
f<4,5,6,...,60>(x,y)
f<10,20,....,50,60>(x,y)
```

(in another application of the library, the set of parameters might be different but still only a few)

This is all fine but not very elegant...

I am looking for some "nicer" way to group these parameters in a cleaner way.

Ideas: 
- create many PARAMS types full of constexpr[s]
- An abstract class with methods to be overriden (not sure if I can mix that with constexpr..)

I was wondering if there is some other nicer way or something available in boost that would be a good match for my problem.

EDIT:
Something similar to this would be perfect! (clearly this is NOT working). And the most important thing is that I need compile time evaluation.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Params1
{
    constexpr static int a = 2;
    constexpr static double b = 4;
    constexpr static int c = 6;
};

struct Params2
{
    constexpr static int a = 1;
    constexpr static double b = 4.3;
    constexpr static int c = 3;
};

template<P>
double f(double x)
{
    return x*P.a*P.b*P.c;
};


int main() {

    std::cout << f<Params1>(1.2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f<Params2>(1.2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite `f()` as follows and your last (post "edit") example should work

```
template <typename P>
double f(double x)
{
    return x * P::a * P::b * P::c;
}
```

The points are

(a) change `template <P>` with `template <typename P>`

(b) and use `P::a`, `P::b` and `P::c` (static values inside a **type**) instead of `P.a`, `P.b` and `P.c` (values of an object)

Comment: yes, I wrote that very fast. That was the original idea but I was looking for something nicer.

Comment: @purpletentacle - the problem is the `double` value that can't be a template value; with only integer, `P` can be a template class and you can replicate the `std::integer_sequence` solution using `P`; with `double` values, the best I can imagine is the `static constexpr` values inside a class (that ins't nicer to use).

Comment: I will accept this one. I appreciate the effort you made in helping me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to understand your requirement but...

> These parameters are fixed and I have 4 or 5 set of values (a1..a10) (b1..b10), etc..

I suppose you could use `std::integer_sequence` and define 4 or 5 types

```
using set1 = std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, ....>;
using set2 = std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 4, 6, ....>;
using set3 = std::integer_sequence<int, 10, 20, 30, ....>;
// ...
```

define the function this way

```
template <int a, int b, int c, int d, ..., int m>
double f (std::integer_sequence<int, a, ...> const &, double x, double y)
 { .. }
```

and call it as follows

```
f(set1{}, x, y);
f(set2{}, x, y);
f(set3{}, x, y);
// ...
```

The following is a full example (but only with 3 template integer)

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using set1 = std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>;
using set2 = std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 4, 6>;
using set3 = std::integer_sequence<int, 10, 20, 30>;

template <int a, int b, int c>
double f(std::integer_sequence<int, a, b, c> const &, double x, double y)
 { return a*(x+y)+b*(x-y)+c*(y-x); }

int main ()
 {
   double x { 1.0 };
   double y { 2.0 };

   std::cout << f(set1{}, x, y) << std::endl; // print 4
   std::cout << f(set2{}, x, y) << std::endl; // print 8
   std::cout << f(set3{}, x, y) << std::endl; // print 40
 }
```

Comment: Thanks max66. That would work but I would have to use indexes.. and the code would look more complex than it should. I would like to keep using names for each parameter.

Comment: the keys points are: I want compile time evaluation and clean names

Comment: @purpletentacle - inside `f()` you can use the names (`a`, `b`, `c`, ...)

Comment: @purpletentacle - answer modified with a reduced (only 3 template integer) example

Comment: Thanks. I was playing with the idea

Comment: maybe I oversimplified the problem and my types are not always ints. :(

Comment: I updated the question with an example of what would be ideal.

Comment: @purpletentacle - I see... the problem is the `double` value that can't be a template parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Your given example code works quite well with some minor changes. Maybe thats what you are searching for?

```
struct Params1
{   
    constexpr static int a = 2;
    constexpr static double b = 4;
    constexpr static int c = 6;
};  

struct Params2
{   
    constexpr static int a = 2;
    constexpr static double b = 4;
    constexpr static int c = 6;
};  

template<typename P>
double f(double x)
{   
    return x*P::a*P::b*P::c;
}   


int main() {

    std::cout << f<Params1>(1.2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f<Params2>(1.2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is some way of having an abstract class that makes clear to library users how typename P should look like. Just wondering if there is a better way